# jsPDF + rasterizeHTML not working?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

jsPDF's `addHTML` requires `html2canvas.js` or `rasterizeHTML.js`.

I want to use `rasterizeHTML.js` but it doesn't work. Couldn't find any example online.

**Working with `html2canvas.js`:**

html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>


<body>
    <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</body>
```

js

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

**Not working with `rasterizeHTML.js` (nothing happens; no errors):**

html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.2.61/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rasterizehtml/1.2.2/rasterizeHTML.allinone.js"></script>


<body>
    <p id="to-pdf">HTML content...</p>
</body>
```

js

```
var pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.addHTML(document.body,function() {
    pdf.save('web.pdf');
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did u have any news about this?

Comment: Is this still an issue? What error message do you see? I'm trying to use rasterizeHTML.js with jspdf 1.5 and getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inlineReferences' of undefined" at line 1009 of rasterizeHTML.js.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem recently and managed to piece together a working example from various sources.

Basic HTML

```
<div id="canvas" width="100%">
    <table class='CSSTableGenerator'>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Cost</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Milk</td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
            <td>Cow puss</td>
            <td>Out Of Stock</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Milk</td>
            <td>$1.00</td>
            <td>white stuff</td>
            <td>Out Of Stock</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<button id="download">Create PDF</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#download').click(function () {
        html2canvas(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
                doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
                doc.save('download.pdf');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andyg2/mtLqparw/

**Resources**

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js